# How to authorise someone just for creating Surveys?

Tags: permissions, survey-list

I have a simple intranet portal which we now want to gradually expand to make use of surveys, blogs etc.

I want to authorise a small group of people to be able to create surveys but not to be able to edit other existing pages and lists etc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since every item in SharePoint (e.g. Document Library's, Lists, Surveys, Blog Posts/Comments, etc.) allows for modular security that can be very granular and is different from the parent site it lives within.

I've done the same thing many times with all the different components of SharePoint.  What I would do is on the site that holds the survey first make sure that small group already has Visitor level, creating a new SharePoint Security Group called something like 'Survey Members' and putting them in there either by an Active Directory group or by individual names.  Then split the permissions off from the parent site which copies them (Survey Settings-->Permissions menu) along with your new Security group.  In the same Permissions menu click on the Survey Members group name to change its permission level.  On the new screen click the Members check box and uncheck the Visitors box.

Now those users will have the ability take and/or edit surveys depending on the other Survey settings.

Hope that helps.

Comment: this solution only lacks the prohibitive part: the users will still be able to create lists and document libraries not pertaining to the Survey type. but yes, only within the 'Surveys' subsite.

Comment: Splitting just the Survey List off with unique permissions will stop those users from creating any other type of SharePoint item.

Answer (score 0):

I think the viable solution would be to develop a custom webpart that would collect the information about the survey which would later be used in an ElevatedPermissions subroutine with SPWeb.Lists.Add and so on. This subroutine could also assign a Manage Lists permission to this user on the newly created list of type Survey.

Comment: I would give +1 for answering but I don't have the points - sorry. Sounds complicated though. To be honest I haven't a clue where to begin with it. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Right, that's not point and click, unfortunately.

Comment: btw, you can use the 'answer' check, which you can later move to a more suitable answer.